# where is the code of the title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want know what is the php file and where wordpress put the title.

This is because I want to use the tag map and put 2 links in the same title.

Is frustrating, because with firebug I can see it. But later in PHP in don't find it.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ok. imaginate that my web page have the same title that stackoverflow. An if you click in stack you go to one web and if you click in overflow you go to another web. I can do this with this html code `<img src="Cabecera0" width="960" height="130" border="0" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,295,125" href="http://www.web.com" />
<area shape="rect" coords="664,0,959,125" href="http://www.anotherweb.com" />
</map>`

But in wordpress I can only associate a link to a image. For this reason, I want to know where I can write this code in all the php sheets.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use get_the_title() and get_the_permalink() to craft your solution. 
It sounds like you are trying to over complicate the solution.